# cart page is not showing in magento

Tags: magento

hi i have made the some changes in checkout.xml and after this cart page stop showing so i have again revert all the changes. but still cart page is not showing. then i download the theme folder and place it in default magento and everything looking as it appear before.
so i think there might be some wrong entry in database. can anyone tell the table name so i can modify that.
thanks

Comment: did you clean the cache? what changes have you made? try to install on fresh database to check your assumption

Answer (score 0):

Magento has some [database documentation](http://www.magereverse.com/) you can use. Not a specific answer to your question, but hopefully this will point you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Enable" Mage_Checkout from your Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Advance. If it is Disable then Enable it.